# How to use the at() method in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am using Pyomo and I have the following lines

```
outputVariables_list = [model.param1, model.variable1]
optimal_values_list = [[pyo.value(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list]
```

When I run it I get a warning that I don't understand:

```
WARNING: DEPRECATED: Using __getitem__ to return a set value from its
    (ordered) position is deprecated.  Please use at()  (deprecated in 6.1,
    will be removed in 7.0)
```

I tried the following line but this led to an error:

```
optimal_values_list = [[pyo.at(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list]
```

Further, I tried to use `pyo.value(model_item.at[key])` and `pyo.value(model_item.at(key)` and both lead to AttributeError: 'IndexedParam' object has no attribute 'at'.

How can I use the `at()` method recommended by Pyomo? What I don't understand is that Pyomo tells me to use "at" instead, but this not work as I get errors when using at. This is a quite confusing recommendation. Any idea how can I can integrate the at() method in my code?

Here is the full list of pyomo components that I use can be seen in the following line (the name indicates if it is a parameter, variable or set): `outputVariables_list_BT2 = [model.param_helpTimeSlots_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW_BT2, model.variable_help_OnlyOneStorage_BT2, model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage_BT2, model.variable_usableVolumeDHWTank_BT2,  model.variable_electricalPowerTotal_BT2, model.variable_pvGeneration_BT2, model.variable_windPowerAssigned_BT2,  model.param_heatDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_DHWDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_electricalDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_pvGenerationNominal_BT2, model.param_outSideTemperature_In_C, model.param_windAssignedNominal_BT2,  model.param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.param_COPHeatPump_DHW_BT2, model.param_electricityPrice_In_Cents, model.set_timeslots]`

**Update**: What I actually want is to store the output in a pandas dataframe by using the code:

```
    #Create pandas dataframe for displaying the results of BT2
    outputVariables_list_BT2 = [model.param_helpTimeSlots_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW_BT2, model.variable_help_OnlyOneStorage_BT2, model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage_BT2, model.variable_usableVolumeDHWTank_BT2,  model.variable_electricalPowerTotal_BT2, model.variable_pvGeneration_BT2, model.variable_windPowerAssigned_BT2,  model.param_heatDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_DHWDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_electricalDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_pvGenerationNominal_BT2, model.param_outSideTemperature_In_C, model.param_windAssignedNominal_BT2,  model.param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.param_COPHeatPump_DHW_BT2, model.param_electricityPrice_In_Cents, model.set_timeslots]
    optimal_values_list_BT2 = [[pyo.value(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list_BT2]

    results_BT2 = pd.DataFrame(optimal_values_list_BT2)
    results_BT2= results_BT2.T
    results_BT2 = results_BT2.rename(columns = {0:'timeslot', 1:'variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating', 2:'variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW', 3:'variable_help_OnlyOneStorage', 4:'variable_temperatureBufferStorage', 5:'variable_usableVolumeDHWTank',    6:'variable_electricalPowerTotal',  7:'variable_pvGeneration', 8:'variable_windPowerAssigned', 9:'param_heatDemand_In_W', 10:'param_DHWDemand_In_W', 11:'param_electricalDemand_In_W', 12:'param_pvGenerationNominal', 13:'param_outSideTemperature_In_C', 14:'param_windAssignedNominal', 15:'param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating', 16:'param_COPHeatPump_DHW',  17:'param_PriceElectricity [Cents]', 18:'set_timeslots'})
    cols = ['set_timeslots']
    results_BT2.set_index('set_timeslots', inplace=True)
    results_BT2['variable_temperatureBufferStorage'] = results_BT2['variable_temperatureBufferStorage'].round(2)
    results_BT2['variable_usableVolumeDHWTank'] = results_BT2['variable_usableVolumeDHWTank'].round(1)
    results_BT2['param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating'] = results_BT2['param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating'].round(3)
    results_BT2['param_COPHeatPump_DHW'] = results_BT2['param_COPHeatPump_DHW'].round(3)
    results_BT2['variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating'] = results_BT2['variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating'].round(4)
    results_BT2['variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW'] = results_BT2['variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW'].round(4)
    filePath_BT2 = folderPath + "\Combined_BT2.csv"
    results_BT2.to_csv(filePath_BT2, index=False,  sep =";")
```

Actually it works fine but I get this warning that however does not seem to have any effect. Still I am curious why it is popping up.

**Reminder**: My bounty is about to expire and so far I still have not received any answer that solves the problem. Thus, I'll highly appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: I never used Pyomo, but could it be that `model.param1` and `model.variable1` are different types? From your error messages, `set value from its (ordered) position` and `'IndexedParam' object` does not sound to be referencing the same. Maybe you need model.param1[key] and model.variable1.at(key)?

Comment: @PeterBe: if you look at the source code you will see a line like this: "if not self.is_indexed() and (key in self._valid_getitem_keys or type(key) is slice):" if that if statement is true then the warning will pop up. I think there should be something related to the key that you pass to the .value

Comment: Also I see that `outputVariables_list_BT2` includes both variables and parameters, I don't think .value can be used for the parameters. Why don't you separate those two type of objects and after getting the values recombine them?

Comment: If you can give a small example of your code (I know it is hard to share 3000 lines but still small example can be arranged)..., I can definitely look at that.

Comment: @OguzToragay: Thanks Oguz for your comment. You are right that the `outputVariables_list_BT2` includes both sets, parameters, and variables. I uploaded a little bit more of the code and stated my intension that I eventually want to store the output of the optimization in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @PeterBe, do you try investigating which part of the model actually throws an issue? Might this error be appeared when you just print out the optimization results without the Pandas parts?

Comment: @A.Omidi: Thanks Omidi for your comment. Actually it is the very last part of the model after the optimization when the solver has finished its work and the optimal values of the variables have determined. Now I just want to print the end results. And as stated before, it is not an error as you wrote, it is just a warning but the result dataframes look totally fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that your output variables list has objects of different types that have different interfaces to access their data. The objects that are a kind of `Set` are the ones that give the warning about index access, and in fact shouldn't be accessed in this way.

When you iterate over the `Set` objects, you get the items in the set. When you iterate over `Var` or `Param` objects, you get their index values.

To correct the part of your code that you are struggling with, I suggest the following to build `optimal_values_list`:

```py
optimal_values_list = []
for model_item in outputVariables_list:
    if isinstance(model_item, Union[pyo.Set, pyo.RangeSet]) :
        optimal_values_list.append(list(model_item))
    else:
        optimal_values_list.append([pyo.value(model_item[k]) for k in model_item.index_set()])
```

Another approach to getting Pyomo variable and parameter values into a pandas `DataFrame` can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494352. Without much work, you can extend the idea to also get parameters, expressions, sets, etc.

Comment: @pbd: Thanks pbd for your answer. Unforunately your suggested approach yields to the error "NameError: name 'Union' is not defined"

Comment: In the top of your program add `from typing import Union`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now get the error message "    raise TypeError("Subscripted generics cannot be used with"
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks" thrown by the line `if isinstance(model_item, Union[pyo.Set, pyo.RangeSet]):`

Comment: What python version are you using? Try upgrading it to at least 3.10 and check if you're getting the same error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When using Python 3.11 it works. But I noticed that you are not using the recommended `at()` methods from Pyomo. Can you not do this using the `at()` methods as this is the recommended way?

Comment: Do you maybe know an easy approach how to store the output of Pyomo after solving into a pandas dataframe? The link you mentione is not really comprehensive. Is there not a more intuitive approach ideally using the recommended `at()` method? Anyways, I accepted your answer and awarded the bouty to you because at least I don't get the warning anymore. Thanks a lot for that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The `at()` method is recommended for accessing the Set members by index position rather than using square brackets. But for what it looks like you want to do, there is no need to access them by index position; you just need their values.

Comment: The link I mentioned is not comprehensive, but I don't know of anything better. I rolled my own function based on the ideas there. Here is a gist of what I use: https://gist.github.com/pdb5627/48ff0c6077851bf762aa4769e2c20232.  It does not include sets, which is one of the things you are interested in. It is not very sophisticated. But it can get you going.